# Counting points within a distance X from a road

Tags: postgis

I need to find out how many points do I have 30 meters from a road.
I used this query in postgis:

```
select 
    a.ref, count(st_distance (a.geom, b.geom) < 30) as count
from osm_roads a, crime_incidents b
where a.ref='A306'
group by a.ref
```

However my road is in segments and I need to union them to get the total count of points for the road A306. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the distance validation into the `where` clause.

To avoid counting the same point twice - if the point is near 2 segments - , count distinct points using their ID

Also, it is more efficient to use `ST_DWithin` in the `where` clause as it makes use of spatial indexes.

```sql
select 
    a.ref, count(distinct b.id) as count
from osm_roads a, crime_incidents b
where a.ref='A306'
     AND ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 30)
group by a.ref;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is start with a union, then count the points:

```
WITH road AS (
SELECT a.ref, ST_Union(geom) as geom FROM osm_roads WHERE a.ref='A306' GROUP BY a.ref
)
SELECT count(ci.*) FROM road r, crime_incidents ci WHERE ST_DWithin(ci.geom, r.geom, 30);
```